# Bypass IC output to give an LED a voltage boost

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, bypass

I'm attempting to modify a circuit in an existing device, the relevant part of which looks like this:

[image]

The IC controls the LED brightness, as well as having connections to other things. I have replaced the LED with a different one. My problem is the new (blue) LED requires more voltage than the stock (red) one and barely glimmers with the existing supply.

I don't have the resources, skills, or space to do anything elaborate. My idea is to add an extra line, with a resistor of a few hundred ohms, between the LED and the ground, to bypass the IC and give the LED a boost. The LED will still be mainly controlled by the IC, but the extra line will help get it off the ground, so to speak:

[image]

Now my problem is, I'm not really an electrician and I have no idea if this will affect the chip. Will it notice? Will it care? Will it melt?

Comment: What voltage supply is feeding the chip and LED and what forward voltage causes the LED to conduct current at the level you wish it to?

Comment: @Andyaka The supply is 5 volts. I'm not sure what forward voltage I need for the LED because I've already soldered it in, but I believe it to be between 3 and 4 volts.

Comment: What kind of IC is it? A link to the datasheet would be very helpful.

Comment: @ThePhoton It's unmarked and the only thing I know about it is that it's the sole chip sitting on the circuit board of my optical mouse. I was hoping it was possible to give just a general answer about whether this sort of thing could affect a chip or not.

Comment: Is the IC drawing a constant current through the LED? If so then the blue LED just needs a higher voltage.

Comment: @MarkU I am not sure.

Comment: Post pictures of both sides of the mouse pcb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *may* work, but you'll need to experiment and get a bit lucky:

In your second diagram, the effective resistance of the IC + resistor in parallel is going to be less than the resistance of the IC alone, and the smaller your resistance, the more you'll be increasing the voltage drop across the diode. If this is confusing, imagine putting in a resistor that has an extreme resistance:

1) 0 Ohm resistor: This would be like shorting out the path around the IC. All of your 5V drop will be across the LED, and you would probably blow it. Also, all of your current would bypass the IC and the IC would not work.

2) Infinite Ohm resistor: This would be exactly like your first diagram, which is your current situation. The 5V drop is from V(IC) + V(LED).

Somewhere in between these two extremes, you may be able to find a resistance that increases V(LED) without popping it and without letting V(IC) drop too low. You may be able to find it by trying out different resistors. Try starting with a very large resistor and move to progressively smaller resistors until you get the brightness you are looking for.

Since you can't identify the IC or LED voltage requirements, you're going to have to rely on some luck to find an appropriate resistance. Keep in mind that when an IC's supply voltage drops below the minimum, it may not immediately die. You may end up with behavior that *mostly* appears normal, yet periodically fails or acts strangely. It may be hard to tell when you've crossed this threshold without a voltmeter and datasheet to tell you what the threshold is.

Comment: This can be summed up as "Maybe it will work; maybe it won't". But I appreciate it is very hard to be specific when I have not been able to be more specific in the question. I will try this, and thank you for your help.

Comment: I hope it's at least a *little bit* more helpful than that. Unfortunately I don't see a way to calculate anything more specifically since we don't know the requirements of the IC or LED, but I tried to give you a strategy for finding the right resistance value, if such a resistor exists. It may be that there's no value that can boost the LED voltage without dropping the IC voltage too far.

Comment: I tried this strategy, but ultimately what it told me was my LED was optically unsuitable. Although I did manage to gradually increase its voltage without upsetting the IC, either it's not bright enough or it has the wrong angle of light dispersion or wrong wavelength or something, because it didn't work properly with the light sensor. Thanks anyway.